# Tech related riddle

Tags: word, wordplay

Here is a question I found:

Figure out what word the following sentence relates to:
*"Solid Computations Resting on a Smoky Basis"*

Hint 1:

> We make digital visuals

Hint 2:

> WATCHing you SMOKE Everytime

Find an answer and give me a good explanation why the answer is so.

Comment: looks to me like a cryptic clue. Is it?

Comment: You say that this is a question you found. Where did you find it?

Comment: @f'' sorry for the VERY late reply. The story is that a couple of my friends signed up for this inter-school *cough* "tech" competition. There was a section which was kept as a mystery event which was hinted to be puzzles etc. To give an example of how the event would be, several questions were given out and this was one of them which everyone was struggling with. Therefore, I came to this site.

Answer (score 7):

My guess is

> Rockstar (a UK-based visual effects and motion graphics studio). See [here](http://www.rock-star.co.uk/about.html).

Solid Computations Resting on a Smoky Basis

> Solid = Rock, 
> Computations = [Star](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xerox_Star), 
>  Smoky Basis = [Autodesk Smoke](http://usa.autodesk.com/smoke-for-mac/all-customers/?remoteContentID=23095099), which Rockstar uses to create visual effects.

Hint 1

> We make digital visuals 
>  Essentially a rough description of what the company does.

Hint 2

> WATCHing you SMOKE Everytime 
>  I guess the key words focusing on the visual aspect and the use of Autodesk Smoke.

Answer (score 4):

Could it be

> particle effects?

Because

> Particle systems are used for smoke in digital visualisation, and they're essentially computations of many solid particles' positions

Comment: Not the answer I had in mind but it still fits! Good job!

Answer (score 0):

The related word is

> Debugging

via

> Smoke tests

Comment: Sorry but wrong answer :P

Comment: @cr0 wow silly answer haha

Answer (score 0):

If it weren't for the hints, I would have said it's

> Cloud computing.

Because

> Cloud is smokey-like.
>  and solid computations tend to rely more on cloud computing (not 100% sure)